# class object comparison operator not working python

Tags: python, class, comparison

```
def is_after1(t1, t2):
    """true if t1 follows t2 chronologically"""
    if t1.hour > t2.hour:
        return True
    elif t1.hour == t2.hour:
        if t1.minute > t2.minute:
            return True
    elif t1.hour == t2.hour and t1.minute == t2.minute:
        if t1.second > t2.second:
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

So I am trying to run an is_after comparison using time as an object of a class "Time()".
However, when I run the function, nothing happens. Here is my function and the associated values for "time" and "time1":

```
is_after1(time, time1)

time = Time()
time.hour = 12
time.minute = 59
time.second = 30

time1 = Time()
time1.hour = 11
time1.minute = 2
time1.second = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You should either print the returned value or assign it to some variable, otherwise the returned value will be thrown away.

```
print is_after1(time, time1) #prints the returned value
```

or:

```
ret =  is_after1(time, time1) #assings the return value from function to ret 
#do something with ret
```

Answer (score 1):

You really want to define how instances of type `Time()` compare by implementing [special Python hook methods](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names), incorporating your `is_after` method into the class itself.

An [`__eq__` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) will tell Python how two objects are equal, and you can use the [`__lt__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__), [`__gt__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__gt__), [`__le__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__le__) and [`__ge__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ge__) hooks to define ordering comparisons.

Use the [`functools.total_ordering` class decorator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) to minimize the number of methods you need to implement:

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class Time(object):
    def __init__(self, hour, minute, seconds):
        self.hour, self.minute, self.seconds = hour, minute, seconds

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, type(self)): return NotImplemented

        return all(getattr(self, a) == getattr(other, a) for a in ('hour', 'minute', 'second'))

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, type(self)): return NotImplemented

        if self.hour < other.hour:
            return True
        if self.hour == other.hour:
            if self.minute < other.minute:
                return True
            if self.minute == other.mitune:
                return self.seconds < other.seconds
        return False
```

Now you can just compare the `Time()` instances *directly* using the Python `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=` and `==` operators:

```
>>> t1 = Time(12, 59, 30)
>>> t2 = Time(11, 2, 5)
>>> t1 < t2
False
>>> t1 >= t2
True
```